# How to bind reactive angular form into object as two-way databind?

Tags: angular

I have angular form:

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
 firstName: new FormControl(''),
 lastName: new FormControl(''),
});

<form [formGroup]="profileForm">

  <label>
    First Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
  </label>

  <label>
    Last Name:
    <input type="text" formControlName="lastName">
  </label>

</form>
```

Also I have an data object:

```
const person = { firstName: 'firstbla', lastName: 'lastbla' }
```

I want to bind the object into the form.

But when I `form.firstName` change it also reflect the change in `person.firstName`. (two-way data binding).

Is it possible to do in angular reactive form ? I try with patchValue, but it doesn't change the person.

Answer (score 0):

**patchValue** update the values in the form.

Reactive form also works in two way binding. Whatever change you do in form , you can get the values. In this case,you can initialize the form with object values.

```
const person = { firstName: 'firstbla', lastName: 'lastbla' }

profileForm = new FormGroup({
 firstName: new FormControl(person.firstName),
 lastName: new FormControl(person.lastName),
});
```

Whenever you make any changes in the form, before submit you can call:

```
const formValues = profileForm.value;
const firstName = formValues.firstName;
const lastName = formValues.lastName;
```

Comment: I want the person.firstname to be bind as two-way databind in reactive form. without ngmodel, which doesn't happends in your example

Comment: Reactive form  hides this ngModel and do two way binding using formControlName what you have used in form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValueChanges. Form initialisation will be like this,

```
profileForm = new FormGroup({
 firstName: new FormControl(person && person.firstName ? person.firstName : ''),
 lastName: new FormControl(person && person.lastName ? person.lastName : ''),
});
```

You have to create one new method in the `ngOnInit()` after form initialisation method,

```
detectValueChange = () => {
this.profileForm.valueChanges.subscribe((response) => {
      person.firstName = response.firstName;
      person.lastName = response.lastName;
    })
};
```

This way both your form and object's value will be on the same page.